# appengine migration from db to ndb: 500 error: 'PickleProperty' object has no attribute '_db_get_value'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I am in the process of migrating from `db` to `ndb` for my appengine site and i am getting the following error:

`500 error: 'PickleProperty' object has no attribute '_db_get_value'`

The full error is below:

```
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj/44.427757764296494114/handlers/handler.py", line 329, in dispatch
super(SiteHandler, self).dispatch()
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj-/44.427757764296494114/handlers/handler.py", line 130, in dispatch
webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj-/44.427757764296494114/handlers/site_handlers.py", line 112, in get
self.get_not_logged_in()
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj-/44.427757764296494114/handlers/site_handlers.py", line 151, in get_not_logged_in
top_users = [user for user in user_query.fetch(30) if user.has_avatar()][:21]
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py", line 160, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1218, in fetch
return self.fetch_async(limit, **q_options).get_result()
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 383, in get_result
self.check_success()
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 995, in _run_to_list
batch = yield rpc
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 513, in _on_rpc_completion
result = rpc.get_result()
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 615, in get_result
return self.__get_result_hook(self)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2971, in __query_result_hook
self.__results = self._process_results(query_result.result_list())
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 3004, in _process_results
for result in results]
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 194, in pb_to_query_result
return self.pb_to_entity(pb)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 691, in pb_to_entity
entity = modelclass._from_pb(pb, key=key, set_key=False)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3216, in _from_pb
_property_map[property_map_key]._deserialize(ent, p)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1473, in _deserialize
val = self._db_get_value(p.value(), p)
AttributeError: 'PickleProperty' object has no attribute '_db_get_value'
```

I have learned that `_db_get_value` is deprecated, but what do i replace it with? Why is it even being called?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/db_to_ndb) where is explained how to do the migration on app engine, as is mentioned:

"NDB prefers methods over functions. E.g. instead of db.get(key), and db.put(entity), NDB uses key.get() and entity.put()."

Also, remember python 2 is not supported anymore and you need to migrate to python 3 as per is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/).

The ndb model supported for Python 2 is not supported anymore as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model), also, at the same document you can find how to do the migration of the apis [too](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services#datastore).

I think the root cause of this behavior is because your App Engine instance is not updated and due this libraries are not more supported you are facing this issue, the migrating services document [2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/) address to the Datastore mode [Client](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) where you can find out how to install the client library:

pip install --upgrade google-cloud-datastore

Comment: I have looked at the documentations and still am having a hard time with understanding what to do